# How can I link an external css stylesheet to a View in the ASP.NET MVC framework?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have created a Site.css stylesheet under Content folder in my MVC architecture however I don't see any changes in my VIEW after adding styles to it.
How do I link them together?
[Solutions Explorer in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huy4N.png)
VIEW example:

```
@model SchoolProject.Models.Teacher
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Warning: Deleting is permanent</h2>

<div>
    <div>@Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</div>
</div>

<form method="POST" action="/Teacher/DeleteTeacher/@Model.Id">

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, paste it in as text and format it properly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok Thank you! I've just fixed it as it is required.

Comment: Have you added a reference to your ```Site.css``` file to the ```[Pages|Views]\Shared\_Layout.cshtml``` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using Layout page in your View:

Open Views->Shared->Layout.cshtml and to the header drag & drop the Site.css file.

if You not using Layout page in your View, you have to drag & drop the Site.css file in your View.

Answer (score 0):

You can check or link your css inside 'BundleConfig.cs' file.
You can navigate it App_Start>BundleConfig.cs
here you can find code to link your css file

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: This was already there but styles were still not applied in my Views. Instead I dragged and dropped Site.css as was suggested in the answer above and it did the trick.